# What are the types of echo output (Opaque, Semi-Opaque, Clear text)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, echo

I have an assignment from my lecturer to **Write a script that will show each of the 3 types of echo (opaque, semi-opaque, and cleartext)**

The issue is, I don't know what the types are. I have searched online but the only thing I could come up with is how to change the color or echo output.
For example

```bash
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
echo -e "${YELLOW}Hello World!"
```

Kindly assist, please.

Comment: I think this is too broad a question for U&L. It's missing the context of your course (encryption? design and UI? something else?). The technical answer will be straightforward once you understand the question, buit that's not something we can help you with. I would suggest that you go back to your lecturer and ask for clarification or else discuss it amongst your peer group.

Comment: it is an assignment for introduction to basic bash scripting. nothing too advanced.

Comment: That terminology (opaque, semi-opaque) has nothing to do with Bash or shell scripting. A google search brings up mostly this question. So, well, where ever your source materials come from, I wonder if you should try finding some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, this is what I got.

```bash
# specify the location of the interpreter

#!/bin/bash
# declare variable name
name="John Doe"
# echo in plain(clear text) (with no quotes)

echo hello

# displays Semi-opaque (double quotes) Expands variables ($ stuff)

echo “Hello $name”

# display Opaque (single quotes) shows exactly what is in quotes

echo 'Hello $name'
```

Output:

```
hello

“Hello John Doe”

Hello $name
```

Comment: In 30+ years of professional working I can say I have never heard of the terms _transparent_, _semi-opaque_, and _opaque_ in the context of shell quoting.

Comment: Your middle example is wrong. The smart quotes are literal characters so you might as well have written `echo =Hello $name=`, and the variable is not quoted at all here. The `echo` command received three arguments, `“Hello`, `John` and `Doe”`. Switch off any and all smart quoting if you're learning to code.